# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING, expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE

Tags: database, connection

I am having a problem while setting up my database file please help me.
I am testing a filehosting script here at http://toorhamza.host56.com/ and I get this error when opening my website

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING, expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or '{' or '$' in /home/a6788850/public_html/includes/class.database.php on line 23

This is my class.database.php file and line

```
<?php

class Database
{

    // Singleton object. Leave $me alone.
    private static $me;
    public $db;
    public $host;
    public $name;
    public $username;
    public $password;
    public $dieOnError;
    public $queries;
    public $result;
    public $redirect = false;

    // Singleton constructor
    private function __construct($connect = false)
    {
        $Config = Config::getConfig();

        $this->host = $Config->"localhost";
        $this->name = $Config->'test';
        $this->username = $Config->'test';
        $this->password = $Config->'password';
        $this->dieOnError = $Config->dbDieOnError;

        $this->db = false;
        $this->queries = array();

        if ($connect === true)
            $this->connect();
    }

    // Waiting (not so) patiently for 5.3.0...
    public static function __callStatic($name, $args)
    {
        return self::$me->__call($name, $args);
    }

    // Get Singleton object
    public static function getDatabase($connect = true)
    {
        if (is_null(self::$me))
            self::$me = new Database($connect);
        return self::$me;
    }

    // Do we have a valid database connection?
    public function isConnected()
    {
        return is_resource($this->db) && get_resource_type($this->db) == 'mysql link';
    }

    // Do we have a valid database connection and have we selected a database?
    public function databaseSelected()
    {
        if (!$this->isConnected())
            return false;
        $result = mysql_list_tables($this->name, $this->db);
        return is_resource($result);
    }

    public function connect()
    {
        $this->db = mysql_connect($this->host, $this->username, $this->password) or $this->notify('Failed connecting to the database with the supplied connection details. Please check the details are correct and your MySQL user has permissions to access this database.<br/><br/>(host: ' . $this->host . ', user: ' . $this->username . ', pass: ********)');
        if ($this->db === false)
            return false;
        mysql_select_db($this->name, $this->db) or $this->notify();
        if($this->isConnected())
        {
            mysql_set_charset('UTF-8', $this->db);
            $this->query("SET NAMES utf8"); 
        }

        return $this->isConnected();
    }

    public function close()
    {
        if ($this->db)
        {
            mysql_close($this->db);
        }

        $this->db = false;
        $this->queries = array();
    }

    public function query($sql, $args_to_prepare = null, $exception_on_missing_args = true)
    {
        if (!$this->isConnected())
            $this->connect();

        // Allow for prepared arguments. Example:
        // query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = :id", array('id' => $some_val));
        if (is_array($args_to_prepare))
        {
            foreach ($args_to_prepare as $name => $val)
            {
                $val = $this->quote($val);
                $sql = str_replace(":$name", $val, $sql, $count);
                if ($exception_on_missing_args && (0 == $count))
                    throw new Exception(":$name was not found in prepared SQL query.");
            }
        }

        $this->queries[] = $sql;
        $this->result = mysql_query($sql, $this->db) or $this->notify();
        return $this->result;
    }

    // Returns the number of rows.
    // You can pass in nothing, a string, or a db result
    public function numRows($arg = null)
    {
        $result = $this->resulter($arg);
        return ($result !== false) ? mysql_num_rows($result) : false;
    }

    // Returns true / false if the result has one or more rows
    public function hasRows($arg = null)
    {
        $result = $this->resulter($arg);
        return is_resource($result) && (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0);
    }

    // Returns the number of rows affected by the previous operation
    public function affectedRows()
    {
        if (!$this->isConnected())
            return false;
        return mysql_affected_rows($this->db);
    }

    // Returns the auto increment ID generated by the previous insert statement
    public function insertId()
    {
        if (!$this->isConnected())
            return false;
        $id = mysql_insert_id($this->db);
        if ($id === 0 || $id === false)
            return false;
        else
            return $id;
    }

    // Returns a single value.
    // You can pass in nothing, a string, or a db result
    public function getValue($arg = null)
    {
        $result = $this->resulter($arg);
        return $this->hasRows($result) ? mysql_result($result, 0, 0) : false;
    }

    // Returns an array of the first value in each row.
    // You can pass in nothing, a string, or a db result
    public function getValues($arg = null)
    {
        $result = $this->resulter($arg);
        if (!$this->hasRows($result))
            return array();

        $values = array();
        mysql_data_seek($result, 0);
        while ($row      = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC))
            $values[] = array_pop($row);
        return $values;
    }

    // Returns the first row.
    // You can pass in nothing, a string, or a db result
    public function getRow($arg = null)
    {
        $result = $this->resulter($arg);
        return $this->hasRows() ? mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC) : false;
    }

    // Returns an array of all the rows.
    // You can pass in nothing, a string, or a db result
    public function getRows($arg = null)
    {
        $result = $this->resulter($arg);
        if (!$this->hasRows($result))
            return array();

        $rows = array();
        mysql_data_seek($result, 0);
        while ($row    = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC))
            $rows[] = $row;
        return $rows;
    }

    // Escapes a value and wraps it in single quotes.
    public function quote($var)
    {
        if (!$this->isConnected())
            $this->connect();
        return "'" . $this->escape($var) . "'";
    }

    // Escapes a value.
    public function escape($var)
    {
        if (!$this->isConnected())
            $this->connect();
        return mysql_real_escape_string($var, $this->db);
    }

    public function numQueries()
    {
        return count($this->queries);
    }

    public function lastQuery()
    {
        if ($this->numQueries() > 0)
            return $this->queries[$this->numQueries() - 1];
        else
            return false;
    }

    private function notify($err_msg = null)
    {
        if ($err_msg === null)
        {
            $err_msg = mysql_error($this->db);
        }
        error_log($err_msg);

        if ($this->dieOnError === true)
        {
            echo "<p style='border:5px solid red;background-color:#fff;padding:12px;font-family: verdana, sans-serif;'><strong>Database Error:</strong><br/>$err_msg</p>";
            if (strlen($this->lastQuery()))
            {
                echo "<p style='border:5px solid red;background-color:#fff;padding:12px;font-family: verdana, sans-serif;'><strong>Last Query:</strong><br/>" . $this->lastQuery() . "</p>";
            }
            //echo "<pre>";
            //debug_print_backtrace();
            //echo "</pre>";
            exit;
        }

        if (is_string($this->redirect))
        {
            header("Location: {$this->redirect}");
            exit;
        }
    }

    // Takes nothing, a MySQL result, or a query string and returns
    // the correspsonding MySQL result resource or false if none available.
    private function resulter($arg = null)
    {
        if (is_null($arg) && is_resource($this->result))
            return $this->result;
        elseif (is_resource($arg))
            return $arg;
        elseif (is_string($arg))
        {
            $this->query($arg);
            if (is_resource($this->result))
                return $this->result;
            else
                return false;
        }
        else
            return false;
    }

}
```

Please help me thanks.

Answer (score 0):

On this line 23 `$this->host = $Config->"localhost";`
localhost should be using single quotation marks
like  this: `$this->host = $Config->'localhost';`